# putting variable into .load

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a few sections and I want to load each using jQuery,
when each section is selected in navigation I want to hide some static elements in the page, hide other sections (if they have been selected and loaded before) and show the current section,
I can do it by writing click event for every single navigation item and try fading out and fading in those elements, but how can I do it in a short way?

Let's say I have : `#background #elem1 #elem2` 
I want to hide this 3 if any of my navigation links are clicked.

and then I have: `#section1 #section2 #section3 #section4 ...`
which are located in a single file called **content.html**
And a light box, lets say `#light`

So let's say when a user clicks on a link like `#nav-section1`, I want the following to be done:

Fade Out: `#background #elem1 #elem2`
Fade Out: `#section2 #section3 #section4 ...`
Fade In: `#light`
Fade In: `#section1`

My navigation looks like this:

```
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section1" name section1">Section1</a>
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section2" name section2">Section2</a>
...
```

jQuery should be something like this:
(the name of clicked item to be placed here in `.load` : `content.html#name`)

```
$("a.navigation").click(function(event){
    $("#light").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#light").load("content.html #"+$(this).attr('name')+);
}
```

I know it's wrong and it doesn't do all the things I want, so could anyone please kindly correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the syntax error by removing the `+` at the end.

```
$("a.navigation").click(function(event) {
    $("#light").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#light").load("content.html #" + $(this).attr('name'));
}
```

Besides that, your HTML is currently invalid. It should look like this:

```
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section1" name="section1">Section1</a>
```

However, using `name` for this is not really appropriate. Use a `data` attribute instead:

```
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section1" data-name="section1">Section1</a>
```

and change the JS like this:

```
$("#light").load("content.html #" + $(this).data('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `=` after name attribute and you should enclose the value on `quotes`.

Change

```
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section1" name section1">Section1</a>
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section2" name section2">Section2</a>
```

To

```
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section1" name="section1">Section1</a>
<a class="navigation" id="nav-section2" name="section2">Section2</a>
```

You have extra `+` sign at the end of `$(this).attr('name')`

Change

```
$("#light").load("content.html #"+$(this).attr('name')+);
```

to

```
$("#light").load("content.html #"+$(this).attr('name'));
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, how about hiding other sections except the selected one?

Comment: Suppose the sections in $("#light") then $("#light").find('[id^=section']).not('#idOfSectionToShow').hide();